# mysqldump create database if not exist

Tags: mysql

i want to use mysqldump so that it includes the statement to create database if not exists, and drop database if exists.  is this possible? what options can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get MYSQLDump to drop the database before creating it by adding

```
--add-drop-database
```

To your MYSQLDump command. You should already have the create database command in there.

Comment: how do I make create table statement use namespace(db name)

Comment: Only to correct the source code client/mysqldump.c. mysqldump add 'USE `DBNAME`;' statement.

Comment: 'IF NOT EXIST' added, if --databases or --all-databases option was given.

Answer (score 1):

`--add-drop-database` ***and*** `--databases <database_name>` (or `--all-databases`).

If you use `mysqldump --add-drop-database <database_name>`, `DROP DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE` statements will not be added.